# C# выведение в консоле для меня в юнити переменную типа стринг, как сделать?

Tags: c#, unity3d

переменная уже есть, как его вывести ко мне в консоль,
print и сама переменная?

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

В языке С# команда `print` в принципе отсутствует, вместо неё `Console.WriteLine(str);`. А для консоли юнити это команда `Debug.Log(str);`

Comment: Есть еще `Debug.LogWarning` и `Debug.LogError`. И если включить настройку Pause on error (не помню точно название) то можно так приостанавливать выполнение в нужные моменты и смотреть вывод или подключать отладчик.

Comment: @trollingchar, судя по вопросу, аватарке и "о себе", я подозреваю, что возможно Tisand ребёнок-подросток, а ты так жёстко грузишь)

Comment: внешность обманчива. К тому же мой комментарий видит не только он. Кому-то может будет полезна эта информация.